# Possibilities of stress testing in Cypress

Tags: cypress

Might I know what are possibilities of testing in Cypress? If one want to test visiting or creating order for few hundred/thousands of times? I would expect there would be some limitations to address misusing of DDoS attacks, but Cypress as tool might offer some safe and valid solution in this kind of manner.

Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cypress is not the right tool for this. It doesn't handle concurrency or have the type of reporting that a dedicated tool for this would.

I encourage you to look into load testing tools like jMeter (though there are others). These tools will track the timings and compile a report of min/max/mean times as well as any errors.

Ideally you'd leverage something like AWS or Azure for a multi-source load test to get a good idea of how a service may perform under load. You would use this to test the APIs, and not the UI/interface since that load is usually handled via client. (though if you have an [SSR](https://vitejs.dev/guide/ssr.html) setup, you might need to test the interface)

Comment: Thank you! As you suggested I do really need to test endpoint not the UI. I like Cypress because of Javascript technology. Might I ask what would you suggest if I am viable in PHP stack? I was able to think through some CLI PHP Request tool with configuration and I am not sure this might be a good approach. I am also open to Python tools.

Comment: There is no programming is necessary for load testing tools. If you look at jMeter you'll see that you can manage the test through a UI. when you are happy with the test, you can run it from command line. Then if you want to automate it it's just a matter of orchestrating the test. You could run it, as part of ci/cd, from a single instance like a github runner, but your results might be inconsistent. To really get a good sense of load capabilities, you should setup a `distributed load testing` system or use use a service that handles that.

Comment: Thank you, it is not what I expected, but you gave me clear interpretation and approach to move myself further.